# Find function satisfying specific conditions

Tags: calculus, curves

All:

I am wondering if there is function can emulate a curve that satisfies:

```
[1] Passing (0,0) (90,50) (100,100)
[2] Continuous and Smooth (left-lim == right lim)
[3] Keep rising(100>=x1>x2>=0 then y1>=y2)
```

I feel it does not exist( or if you can prove it exist and solution is more than one, just give me any one of them), but I do not know how to prove it

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can fit it to a power function of the form $y = ax^k$ for some $a$ and $k$. Solving the system yields:

$$
y = \frac{50}{90^{\log_{10/9}2}}x^{\log_{10/9}2}
$$

[Here's a plot from Wolfram|Alpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20%3D%20%2850%2F90%5E%7Blog_%7B10%2F9%7D%282%29%7D%29*x%5E%7Blog_%7B10%2F9%7D%282%29%7D%2C%20x%3D0..100%2C%20y%3D0..100)

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. Could you teach me how to think this kind of question, why do you start with y=ax(k)? And how did you get this result?

Comment: I sketched the three points on paper and tried to connect them with a smooth increasing curve. I decided that it looked sort of like a parabola, which led me to the model $y = ax^k$. Plugging in the other two points, we get $50 = a(90)^k$ and $100 = a(100)^k$. Dividing the second equation by the first yields $2 = (10/9)^k$ so that $k = \log_{10/9}(2)$. Plugging this back in lets us solve for $a$.

Comment: Thanks, so this kinda need sorta experience to decide whihc model it use rather than a systematic way to calculate its model.

Answer (score 2):

Use line segments. Take: $$y(x) = \begin{cases} x, \text{ if }x \leq 0 \\ 5x/9, \text{ if } 0 < x \leq 90 \\ 50 + 5(x-90), \text{ if } x > 90\end{cases}$$
The function is continuous, increasing, and passes through all points. Do notice, though, that "smooth" is often used for referring to differentiability.

---

[image]

Comment: very clever indeed

Comment: @Ivo Terek THanks, but the only condition not satisfied is smoooth

Comment: Since you only said "left lim  = right lim" after, I thought that you had misused the word "smooth", so I went for a simpler example (I didn't use softwares and calculators to give that function, I only used geogebra to graph it). But all's well when it ends well :)